# Json From .Net Server to android client

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to call a ApiController from android apllication.
This is the api controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]        
public string Get(string coords)      
{
  using (var context = new Entities())
  {
          var records = from poi in context.Pois
                     where poi.Latitude >= fromLatitude &&
                           poi.Latitude <= toLatitude &&
                           poi.Longitude >= fromLongitude &&
                           poi.Longitude <= toLongitude
                     select new
                     {
                         poiName = poi.Name,
                         poiLatitude = poi.Latitude,
                         poiLongitude = poi.Longitude
                     };

          return JsonConvert(records);
      }
  }
}

private string JsonConvert(object records)
{
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records,);
}
```

At the android code, I'm creating json array with new JSON(string).
The problem is java throws an excetpion: the json string is not valid.
When i look at the debuuger, I see that the string have 2 backslash before ",
and java dont know how to parse that.

Where is the problem?
Thank you

Update: Solved. The WebApi returned XML with the json as string. changed the WebApi Not to return XML, then changed it to return object (and removed the JSONConvert) - and it works.

Comment: Posting some example JSON might help.

Comment: This is the value of the JSON:
"[{\\"poiID\\":1,\\"poiLatitude\\":32.00127,\\"poiLongitude\\":34.8212547\\"}]"

Comment: To parse I create JSONArray - org.JSON.JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but i had a similar problem and found a solution.

In my case i had to pass a complex JSON object (nested) from a .NET Client to a Java Rest API and was using a string parameter which turned out to be an invalid JSON due to the double backslash (I seralized it so it was escaped and then .NET escaped it again before sending).

So, in order to avoid that i used StringContent

```
MyType obj = new MyType()
{
...
};

string obJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
StringContent sc = new StringContent(obJSON, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(ruta, sc).Result;
```

Hope this helps someone!